# Completed main mission in Mass Effect 3 but can't go back and do others

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have completed the game but when I go back to play more side misssions the game only lets me replay the raid on illusive man base and the final battle on earth. I have tried 3 times and have gotten 3 different endings, which is cool. but I want to play some more battles and such.

Comment: Load an earlier save or start a NewGame+ ?

Answer (score 4):

Many missions become locked at set points in the story. Once you reach those milestones, the only ways to replay the locked missions are to start a New Game + (as Steve V. mentioned), load a save prior to the milestones, or start a new level 1 character.

Take a look at [this list](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=360949) to see where in the story each mission locks and unlocks for your next playthrough to make sure that you don't miss any!

Comment: @Gomibushi You're welcome :-)